# Section* displayed in minitoc and not in "normal"toc

Tags: table-of-contents, minitoc

I have managed to create a minitoc at the start of a chapter and added section* to the minitoc. However I wanted a solution that those section with a star are only visible in the minitoc and not the normal table of contents. How can I realize this?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\begin{document}
\dominitoc
\tableofcontents %In this table of contents only the sections without a star section{} and not section*{}

\chapter{Title chapter 1}
\section{Title of subsection one}
content... 

\section{Title of subsection two}
content.... 

\chapter{Title chapter 2} 
\minitoc %In this table of contents all sections also section*{}. 

\section{Title of subsection one}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Title of subsection one}
content...

\section{Title of subsection two}
content...
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: \documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\begin{document}
\dominitoc 
\tableofcontents
%In this table of contents only the sections without a star section{} and not section*{}

\chapter{Title chapter 1}

\section{Title of subsection one}
content...
\section{Title of subsection two}
content....

\chapter{Title chapter 2}
\minitoc 
%In this table of contents all sections also section*{}.

\section{Title of subsection one}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Title of subsection one}
content...
\section{Title of subsection two}
content...
\end{document}

Comment: You can edit your question, so rather than adding new information (such as MWEs) in comments, add it to the question itself. You can highlight code by selecting it and clicking the `{}` button above the text field.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one possible solution using the [`titletoc`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titletoc) package; the idea is to use `\addcontentsline` with extension `ptc` (the default extension used by `titletoc` for the partial ToCs) to include information in the partial ToC only:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\startcontents
\chapter{Test Chapter}
\printcontents{}{1}{}

\section{Test Numbered Section}
\section*{Test Unnumbered Section}
\addcontentsline{ptc}{section}{Test Unnumbered Section}
\section{Another Test Numbered Section}
\section*{Another Test Unnumbered Section}
\addcontentsline{ptc}{section}{Another Test Unnumbered Section}

\end{document}
```

An image of the general ToC:

[image]

An image of the partial ToC at the beginning of the chapter:

[image]