# Show chapter* in parttoc but not main toc

Tags: table-of-contents, minitoc

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{0} 

\begin{document}
\doparttoc
\tableofcontents

\part{Part 1}
\parttoc
\addstarredchapter{Chapter}
\chapter*{Chapter}
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\chapter{Chapter 2}

\part{Part 2}
\parttoc
\addstarredchapter{Chapter}
\chapter*{Chapter}
\chapter{Chapter 3}
\chapter{Chapter 4}

\end{document}
```

Currently the TOC looks like this:

[image]

What I want it to look like is:

[image]

Without loosing it in `\parttoc` as in the following image:

[image]

I don't want to use `titletoc` as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84782/section-displayed-in-minitoc-and-not-in-normaltoc).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `mtchideinmaintoc` environment to hide information in the main ToC:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{0} 

\begin{document}
\doparttoc
\tableofcontents

\part{Part 1}
\parttoc
\begin{mtchideinmaintoc}
\addstarredchapter{Chapter}
\chapter*{Chapter}
\end{mtchideinmaintoc}
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\chapter{Chapter 2}

\part{Part 2}
\parttoc
\begin{mtchideinmaintoc}
\addstarredchapter{Chapter}
\chapter*{Chapter}
\end{mtchideinmaintoc}
\chapter{Chapter 3}
\chapter{Chapter 4}

\end{document}
```

The main ToC:

[image]

An image of one of the partial ToCs:

[image]

One can define a command to do this in a more succinct way:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{0} 

\newcommand\Mychapter[1]{%
\begin{mtchideinmaintoc}
\addstarredchapter{#1}
\chapter*{#1}
\end{mtchideinmaintoc}}

\begin{document}
\doparttoc
\tableofcontents

\part{Part 1}
\parttoc
\Mychapter{Chapter}
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\chapter{Chapter 2}

\part{Part 2}
\parttoc
\Mychapter{Chapter}
\chapter{Chapter 3}
\chapter{Chapter 4}

\end{document}
```

Of course, one could also make this redefinition for the internal command `\@schapter` (in charge of starred chapters); but this *might* have undesired side-effects since internally `\chapter*` is used for several document units (ToC, LoF, LoT, bibliographies, indexes):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{0} 

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\@schapter}[1]{%
\begin{mtchideinmaintoc}
\addstarredchapter{#1}
  \if@twocolumn
    \if@at@twocolumn
      \@makeschapterhead{#1}%
    \else
      \@topnewpage[\@makeschapterhead{#1}]%
    \fi
  \else
    \@makeschapterhead{#1}%
    \@afterheading
  \fi
\end{mtchideinmaintoc}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\doparttoc
\tableofcontents

\part{Part 1}
\parttoc
\chapter*{Chapter}
\chapter{Chapter 1}
\chapter{Chapter 2}

\part{Part 2}
\parttoc
\chapter*{Chapter}
\chapter{Chapter 3}
\chapter{Chapter 4}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a way to simplify this so that it doesn't have to be done for each `chapter*`? Like some sort of `renewcommand`?

Comment: @ScottWilton one quick way would be to define a new command; please see my updated answer.

Comment: @ScottWiltonone could also think of redefining `\chaper*` to do this, but then some units might be wrongly listed: the ToC, the LoF, the LoT, an eventual bibliography, and eventual index all use internally `\chapter*` and the redefinition might cause those units to appear in the partial ToCs, which might not be desirable.

Comment: @ScottWilton I added to my answer the code doing the redefinition for `\chapter*` directly, but (as I mentioned) this might cause undesired side-effects (although after some tests, it appears to work as expected).