# minitoc for section printing the starred versions of subsection

Tags: titletoc

My objective is to print a mini ToC under a section but this mini ToC should only print the `subsection*` automatically *and not appear in the main ToC*. As a reference, I am using the following: [sample](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/235932/10898) and [another sample](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84782/10898).

What I have gathered so far is that I can use, say:

```
\startcontents[sections]
\printcontents[sections]{}{3}{} % allows printing of subsection* only
```

and

```
\subsection*{Test subsection not in ToC}
\addcontentsline{ptc}{subsection}{Test subsection in ToC now} % must be added manually unless a command is created that takes as argument the subsection.
```

but all of this seems a bit cumbersome.

Can anyone suggest an automatic minitoc creation of `subsection*` level under a section?

For the sake of completion, here is mwe:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\begin{document}

\section*{Contents}
\startcontents[mytoc]
\printcontents[mytoc]{}{1}{}
\section{Test section in ToC}
\subsection*{Test subsection not in ToC}
\subsection{Test subsection in ToC}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can redefine `\subsection` to automate this via [`xparse`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titletoc,lipsum}
\usepackage{xparse}
\let\oldsubsection\subsection
\RenewDocumentCommand{\subsection}{s o m}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\oldsubsection*{#3}%
     \addcontentsline{ptc}{subsection}{#3}}
    {\IfValueTF{#2}
       {\oldsubsection[#2]{#3}}
       {\oldsubsection{#3}}}
}

\begin{document}

\section*{Contents}
\startcontents[mytoc]
\printcontents[mytoc]{}{2}{} % allows printing of subsection only

\clearpage

\section{Test section in ToC}\lipsum[1]
\subsection*{Test subsection now in ToC}\lipsum[2]
\subsection{Test subsection in ToC}\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Will this interfere with the main ToC? I just want to print locally? That is, `mytoc` should only appear under the corresponding section and not under the main ToC.

Comment: I updated the question. Would you suggest to create a new title class similar to subsection? If so one would need to somehow declare commands so that it prints a mini ToC containing it locally.

Comment: @azetina: When I take my answer and add `\tableofcontents` at the start of the document, I get the `\subsection*` *only* in the section ToC, not the `\tableofcontents`. That's because the `\subsection*` ToC-entry is written to `.ptc`, not `.toc`.